# Custom PHP throwing an error {!-ra:0000

Tags: php, php-errors, phpstringfun

We have a need to pull in data from an external source using PHP. I’ve run into this issue before where EE doesn’t like the PHP formatting i’m using, yet it seems to work elsewhere. For example, if i type the same code into phpfiddle it works fine. When i put it into EE i get the error {!– ra:000000007fef5f44000000007fd6e88d –} or something similar. Please see the code below. Any ideas of why this wouldn’t work? I do put the API key in and “URLGOESHERE” is where the actual API URL is.. i just removed for here.Thanks!

```
<?php

require “util/httpful.phar”; 
$API_KEY = “”;
$startAt = 1; 
$maxReturn = 20; 
$url = “https://URLGOESHERE/sws/v1/offers/cruise?filter=supplier_id=26;searchable_destination_id=2&fields=offer_id,title&start;_at={$startAt}&max;_return={$maxReturn}”;
$response = Httpful\Request::get($url) ->addHeader(‘api_key’, $API_KEY) ->send();
$offers = json_decode($response, true); 
$total = $response->body->meta->total;

$returnHtml = “<h1>Top Cruises</h1><ul>”; foreach( $offers[“offers”] as $offer ){ 
$returnHtml .= “<li><a href=”https://URLGOESHERE/index.cfm/cruise/offer/index?offerID={$offer">{$offer['offer_id']} - {$offer['title']}</li>”; 


$returnHtml .= “</ul>”; $returnHtml .= “Showing results {$startAt} - {$maxReturn} of {$total}”;

echo $returnHtml;

?>
```

Comment: Could be one of a bunch of things. I see left and right quotations. 
set debug = 1 to force php errors to the screen.
What's the php version?
Is php turned on in the template? input or output? or is this part of an addon?
What is httpful? Is that the SDK for the API?

Answer (score 0):

Does your php page works outside EE?  I had that kind of problem with a phone script returning an error.