# {!-- ra:000 … - error - how to handle?

Tags: error, php-errors, switchee

it happens to me repeatedly that suddenly the frontend is not displayed correctly (see screenshot attached). I see no trigger, it seems to happen without reason (just changing ordinary html-tags in a template). Even if I copy the template from the working live-system over to the broken dev-system, it is not working in the dev-system. Strange.
[image: broken page in dev-system]
In [another thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/41232/custom-php-throwing-an-error-ra0000), it was suspected that incorrect PHP code could be the cause. But that is not the case for me, if I remove the entire PHP code from the template, the error remains. BUT: If I turn off php in the template settings, the page works again. Similarly, the page works if I remove a larger Switchee branch.

Does anyone have any idea of what can be done here? Could switchee be the culprit? It hasn't been updated in 5 years after all.
Thank you in advance for any help!

**EDIT 26 Jan 2023**

Actually the problem just vanished. A day later the error completely was gone. I know how that sounds, but definitely the problem just vanished. I also deleted all EE-caches while coping with the error, so it wasn't a caching-problem.
Have to mention that there was a similar problem some weeks ago. Suddenly the live system AND the dev-system showed such errors. I solved it for both systems by emptying a template, saving and pasting the same(!) code into it.
Sounds strange - and IS strange, therefore I really would appreciate any help!

Comment: If you set debug to 2 do you see any errors from the template?  What version of EE and PHP are you running.  Gut reaction is that it's a PHP error... could very well be due to a newer PHP version and switchee as a whole.

Comment: Thanks @TomJaeger - I am pretty sure that it's not PHP (because I removed the PHP-code to test, this changed nothing; also nobody changed the php-code when the error appeared). I cannot show debug-reports because the error has vanished. Pleas see edit in the original post. So perhaps only Switchee to blame? :-)

Comment: Ah, good deal.... My gut reaction is that it was likely a PHP error in Switchee (based on your debugging likely NOT the PHP in the template)

Comment: Ah, now I see … Ok, thanks for your help, so the problem might not be solvable without removing Switchee.

Comment: A bit hard to say 100%.  That's really more of a guess.  We'd need to see the error to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tom-jaeger presumed the problem was the addon which threw a deprecation-notice. This lead to the error in the frontend, and it explains why the error suddenly appeared and vanished: The notice was thrown only once.

@mark-croxton helped out by updating the addon Switchee to PHP 8.1 compatibility (thanks!); you can find it on [Github (croxton/Switchee)](https://github.com/croxton/Switchee/tree/feature/php-8.1-compatibility).